# 'Web' module cannot be found while having installed lpthw.web

Tags: python, pip

I'm currently doing the exercise in "Learn python the hard way".

In this exercise i have to install the lpthw.web frame work.

Having installed pip in windows, i open my terminal and hit

```
pip install lpthw.web
```

Everything then ends succesfully.

But when i browse C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\lpthw.web-1.1-py2.7.egg-info and check the installed-files text i can't see the web.py.

Consequently when i try to import it in a simple script i get ImportError.

I don't have python 3 installed as book suggested for possible cause, so i don't know how to work around it.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked my path

```
import sys
sys.path
```

and saw that every single line was using the panda3d path.
As i was not really using it, unistalling it fixed my problem.

Answer (score -1):

For me it was python version control on raspberry pi 
(linux) 2.7 is default and does not work. 
follow: 
https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/python-programming-tutorial-getting-started-with-the-raspberry-pi/configure-your-pi

have other errors now but the import web loads in python. 
cheers!

Comment: Welcome, Please provide information from the link you provided.